# 2GIS API Отображение входов в здания

Tags: javascript, html, 2gis-api

Собственно, карта стандартно проинициализирована:

```
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width:500px; height:400px"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;

    DG.then(function () {
        map = DG.map('map', {
            center: [54.98, 82.89],
            zoom: 13
        });
    });
</script>
```

Каким образом сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на здание отображались подъезды и входы в него?